# Can't make wget reject/exclude files from a list

Tags: wget, exclude

The problem is this, I have a file with a list of URLs, say `links.txt`:

```
http://www.tipsfor.us/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/vim-editor-icon.png
http://wp.psyx.us/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/vi-vim-tutorial-1.gif
http://proft.me/static/img/vim/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif
```

What I'm trying to do is let `wget` know that I don't want it to get `png` like so:

```
$ wget -R png -i links.txt
```

But this has no effect and `wget` still gets `png` files along with others. Piping `links.txt` through `grep` is not an option as in actual file the links are in this form `http://example.com/get/123987562` that then gets resolved/redirected into something like `http://example.com/media/images/cool-pic.jpg`

So the question is, how do I reject/exclude certain files with `wget`?

Comment: Is order important? Try `wget -i links.txt -R png`

Comment: Nope. Order is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wget, or at least the version I have appears poorly equipped to do this, the `--server-response` option still seems to download the file. If wget isn't critical, then curl may be a better option.

The solution to this type of problem involves looking at the Content-Type returned by the server. For example:

```
curl -I http://www.tipsfor.us/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/vim-editor-icon.png
```

writes the something like the following on stdout

```
http://www.tipsfor.us/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/vim-editor-icon.png
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx admin
Date: Thu, 03 Nov 2011 09:22:55 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 35765
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Apr 2011 05:19:19 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 09:22:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
X-Cache: HIT from Backend
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Filtering that result with grep allows you to test for acceptable mime types. You can then generalize the approach to check for valid mime types for lists of files. Tidying this up and putting it into a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# in mimechecker.sh

LINKFILE=$1
PATTERN=$2

function mimefilter {
    URL=$1
    PATTERN=$2
    curl -sI $URL | egrep ${PATTERN} > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ] ; then
        wget $URL
    fi
}

(
    while read line
    do
        mimefilter $line $PATTERN
    done
) < $LINKFILE
```

Which you would call in this way:

```
mimechecker links.txt 'image/png'
```

Comment: Great idea, thank you for sharing and answering my question. That really helped.